# MySql - How to optimize query with indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join, innodb

We're trying to get the latest 10 notifications for a follower from the database. There are a few joins we do to ensure we get the correct set of notifications for the follower. If the person they follow (their leader) added a new post, the follower should only get the notification for posts that were added after they started following the leader (no sense in showing them their leader's older posts as new notifications). The other join is to make sure we get the notification's `read_at` time,so the follower knows if it was already read or not. Here is the query, but it takes **~9 secs** which is too slow. It should ideally only take a few ms, specially with the indexes:

**Query:**

```
SELECT nf.id, nf.uuid, nf.leader_id, nf.data, nf.created_at, nfr.read_at
FROM notification_followers nf
LEFT JOIN user_follows uf ON uf.leader_id = nf.leader_id AND uf.follower_id = 14 AND uf.follow_status = 'follow'
LEFT JOIN notification_followers_read nfr ON nf.id = nfr.notification_followers_id AND nfr.follower_id = 14
WHERE (nf.created_at > uf.created_at)
ORDER BY nf.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

**Indexes:**

```
ALTER TABLE `notification_followers` ADD INDEX `nf_lid_ca_id_idx` (`leader_id`,`created_at`,`id`);
ALTER TABLE `user_follows` ADD KEY`uf_fid_lid_fs_ca_idx` (`follower_id`,`leader_id`,`follow_status`,`created_at`)
ALTER TABLE `notification_followers_read` ADD INDEX `nfr_fid_nfid_ra_idx` (`follower_id`,`notification_followers_id`,`read_at`);
```

**Explain:**

[image]

**Correct Results (take ~9 secs):**

[image]

**SQL DUMP:**

[SQL DUMP TO REPRODUCE LOCALLY](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NVr8hHeJcwJVsjO62cIohSsjzeRNT5zg/view?usp=sharing) just create `speed_test` database locally and import file to see the slow query issue live with all the table data *(~100K rows)*.

How can we optimize the above to get the correct results within a few ms?

Comment: This is an inner join, right?

Comment: Not sure, but returns the correct results with the current `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Will notification_followers_id exists in notification_followers_read table after the notification got to read or available always?

Comment: After it got read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT nf.id, nf.uuid, nf.leader_id, nf.data, nf.created_at, nfr.read_at
FROM notification_followers nf JOIN
     user_follows uf 
     ON uf.leader_id = nf.leader_id AND uf.follower_id = 14 AND
        uf.follow_status = 'follow' LEFT JOIN 
     notification_followers_read nfr
     ON nf.id = nfr.notification_followers_id AND nfr.follower_id = 14
WHERE nf.created_at > uf.created_at
ORDER BY nf.id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

I would recommend indexes on `user_follower(leader_id, follower_id, follow_status, created_at)` and `notification_followers_read(notification_followers_id, follower_id, read_at)`.  The order of the columns in the indexes matters.

Notice that I changed the first `JOIN` to an inner join, because the `WHERE` clause turns it into one anyway.

Hmmm, let's try rewriting the query:

```
SELECT nf.id, nf.uuid, nf.leader_id, nf.data, nf.created_at,
       (SELECT nfr.read_at
        FROM notification_followers_read nfr
        WHERE nf.id = nfr.notification_followers_id AND nfr.follower_id = 14
       ) nfr
FROM (SELECT nf.*
      FROM notification_followers nf 
      WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM user_follows uf 
                    WHERE uf.leader_id = nf.leader_id AND uf.follower_id = 14 AND
                          uf.follow_status = 'follow' AND nf.created_at > uf.created_at
                   )
      ORDER BY nf.id DESC
      LIMIT 10
     ) nf;
```

For this, you want to be sure you have an index on `notification_followers(id)` as well.

Depending on your data, the inner subquery might be faster with this approach:

```
FROM (SELECT nf.*
      FROM user_follows uf JOIN
           notification_followers nf 
           ON uf.leader_id = nf.leader_id AND nf.created_at > uf.created_at
      WHERE uf.follower_id = 14 AND uf.follow_status = 'follow' 
      ORDER BY nf.id DESC
      LIMIT 10
     ) nf
```

For this, the indexes are `user_follows(follower_id, follow_status, leader_id, created_at)` and `notification_followers(leader_id, created_at, id)`.  This might be faster.

Comment: Hmmm... implemented your query/indexes, but it takes **~7 secs**. Btw, your query is missing the `LIMIT 10` which I added to your query, but still a long time to get the results.

Comment: So the rewritten query with your original index recommendations works really fast on follower_id `14` (takes a few ms), but when I change it to follower_id `1`, no results come back, which is correct but it takes ~4s to return no results. Is there anyway to make it comeback faster like `14` does? Btw, I tried replacing the inner subquery with the respective indexes, but it was still slow for `14`

Comment: Any feedback on my last comment?

Comment: @Wonka . . . Not really.  It is not clear why the choice of id would matter, unless "1" has many, many more rows associated with it.

Comment: Actually, 1 does not have any rows associated with it, which is why it's weird that it takes more than a few ms to return that it has no results. Either way, your query really helped improve the speed, so thank you for the restructured query and index recommendation :)

Comment: I'm wondering whether transforming the left join to a subselect would keep the same results as in the original query. If the relationship between nf and nfr isn't 1:1, the query would return different results (as the left join would add more rows in the original query, which won't be added once the left join is gone). I can see the join is not on the primary key of nfr, but `notification_followers_id` us used, so there is no such promise that the relationship is 1:1. Can you clarify please?

Comment: @Tomer . . . It is not assuming a 1-1 relationship.  It is assuming uniqueness based on the conditions in the correlation clause.  If the results were not unique, then you would get an error, so that seems like a reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```
SELECT nf.id, nf.uuid, nf.leader_id, nf.data, nf.created_at, nfr.read_at 
FROM notification_followers nf 
JOIN user_follows uf ON uf.leader_id = nf.leader_id and nf.created_at > uf.created_at AND uf.follow_status = 'follow'  AND uf.follower_id = 14 
LEFT JOIN notification_followers_read nfr ON nf.id = nfr.notification_followers_id AND nfr.follower_id = 14 
ORDER BY nf.id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Create indexes on.

```
ALTER TABLE `notification_followers` ADD INDEX `nf_lid_ca_id_idx`(`leader_id`,`created_at`,`id`);
ALTER TABLE `user_follows` ADD KEY`uf_fid_lid_fs_ca_idx`(`leader_id`,`created_at`,`follow_status`,`follower_id`)
ALTER TABLE `notification_followers_read` ADD INDEX `nfr_fid_nfid_ra_idx`(`notification_followers_id`,`follower_id`,`read_at`);
```

Comment: Your query does not return the correct results in the question.

Comment: I have putted comment on your question and work on that assumption, Now i have corrected according to your comment.

Comment: So this takes ~4 secs for id `14` to return the results, instead of a few ms. On the other hand, it takes a few ms for id `1` to return the result (that there are no items) which is correct. So it is the opposite times from Gordon Linoff's answer above (seen in my comments there). I was hoping to get a few ms for both, whether id `14` or `1` is used.